# How connect autoform, meteor methods, check arguments and field with autovalue?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform with methods. On server side, of couse, I have to use `check(item, Schema.item)` method. Everything was fine, until I decided to add a field `createdAt` with autovalue. Now I can't pass check() in the method, because this field is not formed, and I want to insert AutoValue ... what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call clean before you call check if you're not using collection2 which calls clean for you.

clean(doc);

clean() invokes your autoValue functions.